# Reforging (Rochet2) to AzerothCore

Tags: c++, azerothcore

Does anyone has already successfully added [Rochet2's Reforging script](https://github.com/Rochet2/TrinityCore/tree/reforging_3.3.5/src/server/scripts/Custom/Reforging) on [AC](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) ?
Mine works but not completely. 
On character login the script should re-apply bonuses on reforged (& equipped) items, but it seems "**player->GetItemByGuid()**" can't find the requested item, so it's returning nothing.

TrinityCore code (works) :

```
uint32 lowGUID = (*result)[0].GetUInt32();
Item* invItem = player->GetItemByGuid(ObjectGuid(HighGuid::Item, 0, lowGUID));

if (invItem) 
    player->_ApplyItemMods(invItem, invItem->GetSlot(), false);             

ReforgeData& data = player->reforgeMap[lowGUID];
data.increase = (*result)[1].GetUInt32();
data.decrease = (*result)[2].GetUInt32();
data.stat_value = (*result)[3].GetInt32();
if (invItem)
     player->_ApplyItemMods(invItem, invItem->GetSlot(), true);
```

AzerothCore code (works, but "if (invItem)" condition never satisfied.

```
uint32 lowGUID = (*result)[0].GetUInt32();
Item* invItem = player->GetItemByGuid((uint64) MAKE_NEW_GUID(HIGHGUID_ITEM, 0, lowGUID));

if (invItem /*&& invItem->IsEquipped()*/)
      player->_ApplyItemMods(invItem, invItem->GetSlot(), false); 

ReforgeData& data = player->reforgeMap[lowGUID];
data.increase = (*result)[1].GetUInt32();
data.decrease = (*result)[2].GetUInt32();
data.stat_value = (*result)[3].GetInt32();
if (invItem /*&& invItem->IsEquipped()*/)
      player->_ApplyItemMods(invItem, invItem->GetSlot(), true);
```

**MAKE_NEW_GUID()** returns something that looks like a guid.

But I don't know why "**player->GetItemByGuid()**" can't find the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of arguments to `MAKE_NEW_GUID` is different from `ObjectGuid`  constructor. So since your arguments are in wrong order then the result is also wrong and item is not found. See the definition and use of `MAKE_NEW_GUID` for the correct order of arguments.